# Xamarin Forms show blocking loading message

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a long running task and I want to show a progress indicator and message.

I have tried using the `ActivityIndicator` and while it shows correctly, it allows the underlying controls to be updated.

This `Xamarin` `iOS` code is just what I want but I need to do it in using `Xamarin.Forms`.

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a **custom renderer** that overlays a **BoxView** over the entire screen.  You can customize the **color fill** and the **opacity** to *show underlying contents* to your liking.

You can then center a **Xamarin.Forms** **ActivityIndicator** in the middle of the screen to finish off the same effect.

**Note** - however, currently in **v1.2.3x** there is a bug on **Android** that allows underlying controls to still receive user input events, like a button click, **despite** the **BoxView** being *on-top of everything*.

This issues is apparently resolved in the upcoming **v1.3** release.

**Update 1**

Its not easily extractable as its part of a more complex control, however it isn't that difficult to get a similar effect to that in your link.

Try the following in your page:-

Use a **Grid** as the base (*1 row, 1 column*), and set it to fill the screen, and set the row and column definitions to **GridUnitType.Star**.

You can then create your page content like normal as a **child** of **Grid**, position this *at cell (0,0)*.

For the next part (you could put this in a **control renderer**) so that it could be re-used easily across multiple pages.  If your not that comfortable with **control renderers**, you can always create a function to return a **Grid** object however that you can use across multiple pages:-

- **Grid** as your base

  - **BoxView** as a child of the **Grid**
  - **ActivityIndicator** as a child of the **Grid**.

Once you have the **Grid** result from the above, you can add this also to your page's **Grid** *root control*, position this again - *at cell (0,0)*.

You can then control the visibility of this overlaying panel on your content.

Naturally you will want to set the **IsRunning** property of the **ActivityIndicator** whenever you **show** / **hide** the panel.  Just create a couple methods like **ShowActivityIndicator()**, and **HideActivityIndicator()** perhaps to simplify this though.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach Pete. Do you happen to have any code showing how the custom renderer would work?