# Loader image in xamarin.forms?

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to display loader image. If service is hitting, I want to display loader image in background in Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms has an `ActivityIndicator`: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator
You'll probably find various code examples on how to use it.

If the core problem is how to load something in the background while displaying *any* "loading" indicator, you might look into this example: http://xforms-kickstarter.com/#asynchronous-web-requests

Answer (score 1):

Use Xamarin.Forms' ActivityIndicator. [Click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator/) for details please.

This is how I use it, you just need to create a new property in your view model and call it as IsLoading, if this is set to true, then Activity Indicator will be visible, that is all you need;

```
// IsLoading property in the viewmodel
  public bool IsLoading
  {
      get
      {
          return isLoading;
      }
      set
      {
          isLoading = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
      }
  }


//code sample in xaml
  <Grid Grid.Row="1"
  IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
  BackgroundColor="Black"
  Opacity="0.25">
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <ActivityIndicator  Grid.Row="0"
                      IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"
                      IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}"
                      VerticalOptions="End"
                      HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
  <Label Grid.Row="1"
         Text="Please wait..."
         TextColor="White"
         VerticalOptions="Start"
         HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not very clear,

I guess you just mean you want to notify the user with a loading animation, while a task running in the background is taking some time?

Check http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/
for a quick and easy way to implement that. The code there is quite editable so you can adapt it for your needs.

For a cross platform solution (Xamarin.Forms), you might want to look at:

[Xamarin Forms show blocking loading message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622054/xamarin-forms-show-blocking-loading-message)

Comment: I want in the same way,but i want to display for all three plateform android,ios and windows phone,how we can make for all three.

Comment: Answer edited - The link above should answer your question then

Answer (score 0):

For implementation of Loader or ActivityIndicator, Xamarin has provided pretty good components for iOS and android. i.e. [btprogresshud](https://github.com/nicwise/BTProgressHUD) for iOS and [Andhud](https://github.com/redth/andhud) for Android. These components can be used through Xamarin.Forms.